# Paraview: Properties GUI very wide

Tags: user-interface, paraview

I use Paraview (3.98) to display results from FEM simulations. The Properties detachable window accomodates some settings under `Display (UnstructuredGridRepresentation)`, which creates GUI entries for "Opacity Table Values" and "Radius Table Values", which are very large and make the other settings go beyond the edge of the window. AFAIR it was not an issue in orevious version os Paraview. Is there a way to make the GUI less wide again?

[image: paraview screenshot]

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the mailing list for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a tough time overcoming this problem too, the solution for paraview 3.98 is to use the option `--use-old-panels`.
Or you could upgrade to PV 4.0.1 where this annoying bug has been fixed.

Comment: Hey, cool! I thought I was the only unfortunate guy in the universe. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs with 3.98 when the PointSprite plugin is loaded. You can not load the plugin if you're not using it and that will overcome the issue. As Zony suggested, you can always upgrade to 4.0.1 and this issue will disappear.